# AG-Grid Enterprise: How to replace Column Menu by community filter

Tags: ag-grid

I'm trying the entreprise version of Ag-Grid, but when using this version I can not have the standard "column filter".
It only have a "Columns panels" with a filtering but, this one is more difficult to use.

Is there any way to have the community version of column filter, when using the ag-grid entreprise version (that I need for some other functionnality).

Maybe by specifying some `menuTabs` options... but the doc doesn't help on what is the options available for these menu.

Here is an example of the simple column filter (the functionnality wanted):
https://plnkr.co/edit/HougMsUWbIU2Plhd9rRz?p=preview

Here is an example with the "entreprise filter" (the functionnality that I don't want):
https://plnkr.co/edit/wg6cpAVn7t7rrbX143ug?p=preview

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify [`filter`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/#filter-types) value inside `columnDefs` :

> `agNumberColumnFilter`    A Number Filter for number comparisons.
>
> `agTextColumnFilter`  A Text Filter for string comparisons.
>
> `agDateColumnFilter`  A Date Filter for date comparisons.
>
> `agSetColumnFilter`   A Set Filter, influenced by how filters work in Microsoft Excel. This is an ag-Grid-Enterprise feature.

To get the simple filter you can use: `agNumberColumnFilter`, `agTextColumnFilter`, `agDateColumnFilter` with `menuTabs:['filterMenuTab']`, on this case other tabs would be suppressed.

Or you can use [`floatingFilter`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/#floating-filters) with [`suppressMenu`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/#showing-the-column-menu) `gridOptions` property

As example :

```
filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',  menuTabs:['filterMenuTab']
```

Or:

```
gridOptions.floatingFilter: true
....
filter:'agNumberColumnFilter', suppressMenu: true
```