# How to remove ag-grid default filtering columns

Tags: ag-grid

I tried removing the default filter of ag-grid which hides the column(s) and appears in the most right side of each column header, but I couldn't find the property. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AG-Grid Enterprise: How to replace Column Menu by community filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475553/ag-grid-enterprise-how-to-replace-column-menu-by-community-filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `menuTabs` property in column definition like this -

```
  {
    headerName: "Athlete",
    field: "athlete",
    width: 150,
    filter: "agSetColumnFilter",
    menuTabs: [ 'filterMenuTab', 'generalMenuTab']
  }
```

As per [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/) -

> menuTabs  Set to an array containing zero, one or many of the
>   following options 'filterMenuTab', 'generalMenuTab' and
>   'columnsMenuTab'. This is used to figure out which menu tabs and in
>   which order the tabs are shown

Comment: Can I prevent a column from appearing in the column menu ?